# Global Entry PASSID number

Tags: global-entry

It says on multiple websites that one's 9-digit Global Entry PASSID number should begin with a 98.  However mine begins with a 15.  Does anyone know what this means?

Thanks!

Comment: i agree ...there are so many numbers on the back of the card! I googled and it stated that the PASSID is the number to use and mine starts with 15 as well

Answer (score 1):

It [seems to just be a thing that happens](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/trusted-travelers/1923083-all-ktn-s-supposed-begin-98-99-a.html) without any meaning as far as I'm aware. Some also begin with 99. [TSA seems to say it's fine](https://twitter.com/asktsa/status/1030231513198219264?lang=en).

I'm not aware of any particular significance to it, though it seems to be the case for at least some applicants from the past few months.